# Google Drive C# login withou UI

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I have a google account thehumpt@gmail.com.
I need to develop a Windows desktop software which automatically saves files to google drive.
I've checked some internet links and didn't found any way how to automatically login to my google account without UI login interaction.
Can you tell me possible ways how can my program login to google drive account without UI communication (interaction)? Is it possible?

Regards.

1. I can login to google drive with service account but this is not my case.
2. I've tried access token but this token will expire in one hour and my program cannot access Google Drive after that.

I expect to run my program on regular basis it will save files to my Google Drive.

Comment: You need an OAuth refresh token.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention/19766913#19766913